# What is this Android widget exactly called and how do I implement it?

Tags: java, android

I looked all over googling for possible approaches to implementing this or even knowing what it is, but no amount of googling yielded any results. So please excuse me for this silly question.

What kind of widget is this? I see it used by Youtube for showing video description, and also by Facebook's messenger as a drawer for Emojis and Gifs and all :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment)

extend BottomSheetDialogFragment class and inflate your layout file. After creating the fragment class and the layout file you can call it like this.

```
YourBottomSheet yourBottomSheet = new YourBottomSheet();
yourBottomSheet.show(getParentFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```